# How to change the theme of an existing application developed using jquery-mobile?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am building an application using jquery mobile and phone gap. As I am about to start the application, have a doubt on how to change the theme of an application on the fly or with minimum changes involved so that I can use the same app with different themes for different client.

Please let me know is there a configuration or common place available to update/change the theme of an entire application at any moment during the development.

EDIT: sorry to confuse a bit, the question is with how to switch between the themes provided by default by jquery mobile like a, b, c, d and e without doing any or much code change.

Thanks.

Comment: Say, you have radio button, for changing the theme on fly, then, this is what you need: `$("link").attr("href", "css/yourCustom.css");`  I will post the whole code what i wrote to change themes fly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

jQuery Mobile has 3 different CSS files, you can get them when you download whole package.

- jQuery Mobile CSS file
- jQuery Mobile Structure CSS file
- jQuery Mobile Theme CSS file

If you want to use different themes all you need to do is use second and third mentioned file. Structure CSS holds jQuery Mobile structure CSS and it is a backbone of whole structure. What you need to change is jQuery Mobile theme CSS file. This is a file you get when you create a new theme.

On the other hand jQuery Mobile will have several more CSS files but logic is the same. If you download jQuery Mobile from this link: http://jquerymobile.com/

You will find these files:

- jquery.mobile.external-png-1.4.2.min.css
- jquery.mobile.icons-1.4.2.min.css
- jquery.mobile.inline-png-1.4.2.min.css
- jquery.mobile.inline-svg-1.4.2.min.css
- jquery.mobile.structure-1.4.2.min.css
- jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.2.min.css
- jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css

If you want to use customized themes you will need to remove **jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css** and **jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.2.min.css**. Theme builder will give you new **jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.2.min.css** file, or even if you download it from somewhere you will get alternative **jquery.mobile.theme-1.4.2.min.css** file.

## Update

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LfLFm/

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#index',function (e, ui) {
    $(this).removeClass('ui-page-theme-a').addClass('ui-page-theme-b');
});
```

or even better: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/ML2F6/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforecreate', '#index',function (e, ui) {
    $(this).page({theme:'b'});
});
```

Comment: If I just want to switch between the theme a, b, c, d and e provided by defualt? I do not want to change the whole code, just to make a single switch.

Comment: jQuery Mobile has only two switches. You only want to change page theme on the fly?

Comment: Yes. I just want to have the application flexible enough to switch between the themes on the fly.

Comment: Take a look at updated answer, specially at method 2.

Comment: Thats, great. But it is at every page level. Is is there any configuration at the entire application level which will be applied to all its pages at one go.

Comment: You can do it on application level BUT it can be done only before jQuery Mobile initializes: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/LfLFm/1/ . One other thing, for this solution to work your pages must not have set data-theme attribute. After page is initialized only way to change page theme is via: .page({theme:'b'});

Answer (score 2):

You can simply do it through `.page({ theme : "a, b, c" })` widget. It will change the whole page's theme.

```
$(document).on("pagecreate", function () {
    $(".selector").on("click", function () {
        $.mobile.pageContainer.pagecontainer("getActivePage").page({
            theme: "b"
        });
    });
});
```

> **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Palestinian/Vq92E/)**